# Delete contents of JSON object via table view controller - SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am working on an iOS application which tracks user locations and 1) displays them as map annotation objects and 2) displays the data in a table view controller. The data contained in the table view controller is stored on the end user's iOS device as a JSON file. I am having an issue where I cannot get the records within the JSON file to delete even though delete has been enabled in the code for the table view controller.

I need another pair of eyes to look at the code and hopefully tell me what I'm missing.

The code consists of the following files:

- MapViewController.swift
- PlacesTableViewController.swift
- Location.swift
- LocationsStorage.swift
- Extension to AppDelegate.swift (Only pertinent code included here)

The contents of the files are as follows:

- MapViewController.swift *

  ```
    import UIKit
    import MapKit

    class MapViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    mapView.userTrackingMode = .follow
    let annotations = LocationsStorage.shared.locations.map { annotationForLocation($0) }
    mapView.addAnnotations(annotations)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(newLocationAdded(_:)),          name: .newLocationSaved, object: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func addItemPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    guard let currentLocation = mapView.userLocation.location else {
    return
    }
    LocationsStorage.shared.saveCLLocationToDisk(currentLocation)
    }

    // Delete location pin from mapview
    @IBAction func removeItemPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    guard let currentLocation = mapView.userLocation.location else {
      return
    }
    LocationsStorage.shared.saveCLLocationToDisk(currentLocation)
    }

    func annotationForLocation(_ location: Location) -> MKAnnotation {
    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    annotation.title = location.dateString
    annotation.coordinate = location.coordinates
    return annotation
    }

    @objc func newLocationAdded(_ notification: Notification) {
    guard let location = notification.userInfo?["location"] as? Location else {
    return
    }
    let annotation = annotationForLocation(location)
    mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)}}
  ```
- PlacesTableViewController.swift *

  ```
   import UIKit
   import UserNotifications

   class PlacesTableViewController: UITableViewController {
   override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

   NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
   self,
   selector: #selector(newLocationAdded(_:)),
   name: .newLocationSaved,
   object: nil)
   }

   @objc func newLocationAdded(_ notification: Notification) {
   tableView.reloadData()
   }

   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,   numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   return LocationsStorage.shared.locations.count
   }

   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt   indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PlaceCell", for: indexPath)
   let location = LocationsStorage.shared.locations[indexPath.row]
   cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 3
   cell.textLabel?.text = location.description
   cell.detailTextLabel?.text = location.dateString
   return cell
   }

   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt   indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
   return 110
   }
   // Enables swipe-to-delete functionality in table view. 
   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit     editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)    {
   if editingStyle == UITableViewCell.EditingStyle.delete {
   LocationsStorage.shared.locations.remove(at: indexPath.row)
   tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with:  UITableView.RowAnimation.automatic)
   tableView.reloadData()
   }
   }
   }
  ```
- Location.swift *

  ```
    import Foundation
    import CoreLocation

    class Location: Codable {
    static let dateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .medium
    formatter.timeStyle = .medium
    return formatter
    }()

    var coordinates: CLLocationCoordinate2D {
    return CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
    }

    let latitude: Double
    let longitude: Double
    let date: Date
    let dateString: String
    let description: String

    init(_ location: CLLocationCoordinate2D, date: Date, descriptionString: String) {
    latitude =  location.latitude
    longitude =  location.longitude
    self.date = date
    dateString = Location.dateFormatter.string(from: date)
    description = descriptionString
    }

    convenience init(visit: CLVisit, descriptionString: String) {
    self.init(visit.coordinate, date: visit.arrivalDate, descriptionString:   descriptionString)
    }
    }
  ```
- LocationsStorage.swift *

  ```
    import Foundation
    import CoreLocation

    class LocationsStorage {
    static let shared = LocationsStorage()

    //private(set) var locations: [Location]
    var locations: [Location]
    let fileManager: FileManager

    // documentsURL cannot be private expression.
    let documentsURL: URL

    init() {
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    // Location JSON file is stored in user's home directory on iOS. Inaccessible to PC/Mac    hardware but can be accessed by application.
    documentsURL = try! fileManager.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask,    appropriateFor: nil, create: false)    
    self.fileManager = fileManager

    let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()

    let locationFilesURLs = try! fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(at: documentsURL,
                                                             includingPropertiesForKeys: nil)
    locations = locationFilesURLs.compactMap { url -> Location? in
    guard !url.absoluteString.contains(".DS_Store") else {
    return nil
    }
    guard let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) else {
    return nil
    }
    return try? jsonDecoder.decode(Location.self, from: data)
    }.sorted(by: { $0.date < $1.date })
    }

    // Saves location data to JSON object within user directory
    func saveLocationOnDisk(_ location: Location) {
    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    let timestamp = location.date.timeIntervalSince1970
    let fileURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("\(timestamp)")

    let data = try! encoder.encode(location)
    try! data.write(to: fileURL)

    locations.append(location)

    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .newLocationSaved, object: self, userInfo: ["location": location])
    }

    func saveCLLocationToDisk(_ clLocation: CLLocation) {
    let currentDate = Date()
    AppDelegate.geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(clLocation) { placemarks, _ in
    if let place = placemarks?.first {
    let location = Location(clLocation.coordinate, date: currentDate, descriptionString: "\(place)")
    self.saveLocationOnDisk(location)
    }
    }
    }
    }

    extension Notification.Name {
    static let newLocationSaved = Notification.Name("newLocationSaved")
    }
  ```
- Extension to AppDelegate.swift *

  ```
    // Journaling-specific variables
    static let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    ... [other code here, not related to question]

    extension AppDelegate: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didVisit visit: CLVisit) {
    // create CLLocation from the coordinates of CLVisit
    let clLocation = CLLocation(latitude: visit.coordinate.latitude, longitude: visit.coordinate.longitude)

    // Get location description
    AppDelegate.geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(clLocation) { placemarks, _ in
    if let place = placemarks?.first {
    let description = "\(place)"
    self.newVisitReceived(visit, description: description)
    }
    }
    }

    func newVisitReceived(_ visit: CLVisit, description: String) {
    let location = Location(visit: visit, descriptionString: description)
    LocationsStorage.shared.saveLocationOnDisk(location)

    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "New Location Logged "
    content.body = location.description
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default

    // UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger is set to 10 minutes. User must spend 10 minutes at a location before a notificatin will be triggered and a log will be created.
   let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: (10*60), repeats: false)
   let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: location.dateString, content: content, trigger: trigger)

   center.add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
   }

   func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
   guard let location = locations.first else {
   return
   }

   AppDelegate.geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location) { placemarks, _ in
   if let place = placemarks?.first {
   let description = "Fake visit: \(place)"

   let fakeVisit = FakeVisit(coordinates: location.coordinate, arrivalDate: Date(), departureDate: Date())
   self.newVisitReceived(fakeVisit, description: description)
   }
   }
   }
   }

   final class FakeVisit: CLVisit {
   private let myCoordinates: CLLocationCoordinate2D
   private let myArrivalDate: Date
   private let myDepartureDate: Date

   override var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D {
   return myCoordinates
   }

   override var arrivalDate: Date {
   return myArrivalDate
   }

   override var departureDate: Date {
   return myDepartureDate
   }

   init(coordinates: CLLocationCoordinate2D, arrivalDate: Date, departureDate: Date) {
   myCoordinates = coordinates
   myArrivalDate = arrivalDate
   myDepartureDate = departureDate
   super.init()
   }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
  fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }
  }
  ```

Interestingly, when I am able to delete the records within the table view controller, they appear to delete until the next time the app launches, at which time they are back and still visible.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to save your json file to disk after you delete the item

Comment: @Paulw11 thank you! I knew I was missing something and a second set of eyes was the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As paulw11 stated in comments, needed to save JSON to disk after performing delete action.